# How to retrieve value from map - go lang?

Tags: go, mgo

I am working with `mgo` to use MongoDB with Go. I have the following code:

```
func Find(collectionName, dbName string, query interface{}) (result []interface{}, err error) {
    collection := session.DB(dbName).C(collectionName)
    err = collection.Find(query).All(&result)
    return result, err
}

func GetTransactionID() (id interface{}, err error) {
    query := bson.M{}
    transId, err := Find("transactionId", dbName, query)
    for key, value := range transId {
        fmt.Println("k:", key, "v:", value)
    }
}
```

`Output:`  k: 0 v: map[_id:ObjectIdHex("536887c199b6d0510964c35b") transId:A000000000]

I need to get the values of `_id` and `transId` from the map value returned in the slice from `Find`. How can I do that?

Comment: Work your way through the Go tour http://tour.golang.org/#1 first. Hint: `transId` is a slice (kinda array), the map is element 0 so you might want to do `m := transId[0]` now `m` is the map and the elements can be accessed like `m["_id"]` and `m["transID"]`.

Comment: @Volker thanks i had tried the same. Error is invalid operation: m["_id"] (index of type interface {})

Comment: You will have to show the whole code. It is impossible to guess what the type of the map is. Try printing the stuff with `%+v` and/or `%#v` if you cannot figure out what type your map is.

Comment: @Volker type of transId is interface{}.

Comment: Show whole code in the playground.

Comment: @Volker If this uses `mongoDB` as an earlier edit indicated, I don't know if that's possible since it has a non-standard library import. It looks like this may be the relevant documentation: http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Find It appears that the `Find` method returns a `*Query`?

Comment: @Volker granted, I agree that even if it doesn't run having the whole file will make documentation detective work easier.

Comment: It looks like MongoDB will fill a `results` slice with arbitrary data depending on what the query evaluates to. You have to know ahead of time what the format of the return value will be, you can't figure this out at runtime. I'm not sure if that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: @karthick.k I'm still not clear what you're asking: do you want the values of `transID` and `_id` or the values they map to? That is: do you want the keys or the values from the map?

Comment: @Jsor I want to get `_id` and `transId`. I am getting the value from mongoDB as []interface{} type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm just guessing but in case you just want to retrieve all *Transaction* documents and print them - here is how:

Given you have a `struct` representing the structure of the documents of your collection e.g.:

```
type Transaction struct {
  Id            bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id"`
  TransactionId string        `bson:"transId"`
}
```

You can obtain all the documents using the MongoDB driver (mgo):

```
var transactions []Transaction
err = c.Find(bson.M{}).All(&transactions)
// handle err
for index, transaction := range transactions {
  fmt.Printf("%d: %+v\n", index, transaction)
}
```

**Addition (generic solution)**

OK, after you provided some more insight this might be a generic solution without using a struct. Try to marshall into a BSON document `bson.M` (not tested):

```
var data []bson.M
err := c.Find(bson.M{}).All(&data)
// handle err 
for _, doc := range data {
  for key, value := range doc {
    fmt.Println(key, value)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is it, the documentation says it will fill the slice passed in with data of the correct type, so since it's not a []struct{ bson.ObjectID; string } it replaces that with a single map[bson.ObjectID]string containing all transactions.

Comment: Thanks. I can't specify the struct in the mongoDB query. Because we are using common dbengine for projects. So err = c.Find(bson.M{}).All(&result). result type is []interface{}.