# Obtain ObjectIdHex value from mgo query

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm still new to go and while I see multiple questions on SO similar to this, I'm unable to reproduce the output some OP's had requested ([this answer looking the closest](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23490793/3109182)).

I'm doing something fairly simple, I'm hitting a `users` collection in mongo and all I want to do is get the `_id` value back as a string.  I'm going to eventually push these `_id`'s up to NSQ but that's the brunt of my task.

```
var users []bson.M
err = sess.DB("db_name").C("users").Find(bson.M{}).All(&users)

if err != nil {
    os.Exit(1)
}

for _, user := range users {
    fmt.Printf("%+v \n", user["_id"])
}
```

Today this outputs:

```
ObjectIdHex("537f700b537461b70c5f0000")
ObjectIdHex("537f700b537461b70c600000")
ObjectIdHex("537f700b537461b70c610000")
ObjectIdHex("537f700b537461b70c620000")
```

I went through the [bson#m](http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo/bson#M) docs and thought I was correctly using the map in order to extra the value.  So I think, my query results in:

```
{"_id" : ObjectIdHex("Some_ID") }
```

but if ObjectIdHex("ID") is the value, how do I simply get the string within there.

So ideal output:

```
"537f700b537461b70c5f0000"
"537f700b537461b70c600000"
"537f700b537461b70c610000"
"537f700b537461b70c620000"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value associated with key `"_id"` is of type [`bson.ObjectId`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId) which is simply a `string`.

[`bson.M`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#M) is a type `map[string]interface{}`, so you need [Type assertion](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get the id as an `ObjectId`:

```
objid, ok := m["_id"].(ObjectId)
if !ok {
    panic("Not ObjectId")
}
```

And the `ObjectId` has a [`ObjectId.Hex()`](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId.Hex) method which returns exactly what you want: the object id as a "pure" hex string:

```
fmt.Println(objid.Hex())
```

#### Alternatives

`objid` can simply be converted to `string` because its underlying type is `string`. So you can use a number of further options to convert it to a hex `string`:

```
hexid := fmt.Sprintf("%x", string(objid))
```

If you just want to print it, you can do directly:

```
fmt.Printf("%x", string(objid))
```

**Note:** Converting it to `string` is important else the `fmt` package would call its `String()` method which results in a string like `ObjectIdHex("537f700b537461b70c5f0000")` and this is what would be converted to hex which is clearly not what you want.

**Alternatively** you can use the [`encoding/hex`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/) package and the [`hex.EncodeToString()`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/hex/#EncodeToString) function:

```
hexid := hex.EncodeToString([]byte(objid))
```

Comment: Is there a reason to use `hex.EncodeToString([]byte(objid))` instead of the [Hex](http://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId.Hex) method?

Comment: @BeBop I don't think so. I just didn't know about the `Hex()` method. Should I add it to the answer or you post it as a new answer?