# Why can't I find the ID using the mgo library of golang?

Tags: go, mgo

I am using mgo library for mongo operationg in golang and here is my code :

```
session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true)
coll := session.DB("aaaw_web").C("cron_emails")
var result Result
fmt.Printf("%v", message.ID)
err = coll.FindId(bson.ObjectId(message.ID)).One(&result)
fmt.Printf("%v", result)
fmt.Println(err)
```

I am getting this output :

```
595f2c1a6edcba0619073263
{ObjectIdHex("") 0   0  0    0 {         0    false 0    } 0 0 0  0 0 0 0}
ObjectIDs must be exactly 12 bytes long (got 24)
not found
```

But I checked, document exists in mongo, but getting here no result, any idea what am i missing ...

Comment: right, but mongo object id's are of 24 characters, how should i convert that 24-character id into a 12 character id, i tried  bson.ObjectIdHex as well but no luck,

Comment: ObjectIdHex should work, I'm using this all the time `err := db.C("images").FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(id)).One(&m)`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As the error message hints, an object id is exactly 12 bytes long (12 bytes of data). The 24 char long ID you see printed is the hexadecimal representation of the 12 bytes of the ID (1 byte => 2 hexa digits).

Use the [`bson.ObjectIdHex()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectIdHex) function to obtain a value of [`bson.ObjectId`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId) if the hex representation is available.

```
err = coll.FindId(bson.ObjectIdHex(message.ID)).One(&result)
```

For the reverse direction, you may use the [`ObjectId.Hex()`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson#ObjectId.Hex) method, detailed in this answer: [Obtain ObjectIdHex value from mgo query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146922/obtain-objectidhex-value-from-mgo-query/29148800#29148800)

What you did in your code is a simple [type conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions) (given that `message.ID` is of type `string`), and the syntax is valid because the underlying type of `bson.ObjectId` is `string`, so that basically interprets the 24 characters as `bson.ObjectId` type, but it is an invalid `ObjectId` value because it will be 24 bytes and not 12.